# SELECT occurences of a combination of columns with a minimum condition on the COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, having-clause

I am storing some data everyday in a table OptionsData. In this table I am interested in two columns "asofdate" and "contract". The combination of asofdate+contract should be unique: if not then I need to do some clean up. I would like to return  3 columns as follows:
asofdate !! contract !! count > 1

This will allow me to identify duplicates in my table. I have tried the following:

```
select asofdate, contract, count(*) mycount 
from (select asofdate, contract
      from public."OptionsData"
      group by asofdate, contract
      ) AS DerivedTable
GROUP BY asofdate, contract
HAVING mycount > 1
ORDER BY mycount DESC
```

But this returns an error:

```
ERROR:  column "mycount" does not exist
```

Same thing happens if I specify

```
HAVING DerivedTable.mycount > 1
```

(I also tried a WHERE statement instead of HAVING but this gives another error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

)

Needless to say I am a beginner in sql...

Comment: This would work, if you moved `count(*) mycount` inside the subquery. And `WHERE` instead of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` would suffice in the main query then. But as you can see from my answer, you don't need a subquery (derived table) at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an alias name in the `GROUP BY` clause. Besides: Why the subquery? It reduces the rows to one per asofdate and contract, so if you count *afterwards* you get a count of 1 for each asofdate / contract pair.

```
select asofdate, contract, count(*) as mycount 
from public.optionsdata
group by asofdate, contract
having count(*) > 1
order by mycount desc;
```