# postgreSQL query seems to be running on infinite loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547666/select-occurences-of-a-combination-of-columns-with-a-minimum-condition-on-the-co), I am now trying to remove duplicates from my database. I am first running a sub-query to identify the almost identical records (the only difference would be the index column "id"). My table has roughly 9 million records and the below code had to be interrupted after roughly 1h30

```
DELETE FROM public."OptionsData" 
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (asofdate, contract, strike, expiry, type, last, bid, ask, volume, iv, moneyness, underlying, underlyingprice) * FROM public."OptionsData"
    ) AS TempTable
);
```

Producing the results from the sub-query takes about 1 minute, so maybe running the full query might take a long time (?) or is there something off in my code please?

Comment: How many duplicates do you have?

Comment: Total number of records: 8'764'239
The sub-query indicates: 8'681'440 unique records
So 82'799 duplicates

Humm then assuming 1 sec to delete a records, that would require almost 23hours (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT IN combined with a DISTINCT is usually quite slow.

To delete duplicates using EXISTS is typically faster:

```
DELETE FROM public."OptionsData"  d1
WHERE EXISTS (select *
              from public."OptionsData" d2
              where d1.id > d2.id
                and (d1.asofdate, d1.contract, d1.strike, d1.expiry, d1.type, d1.last, d1.bid, d1.ask, d1.volume, d1.iv, d1.moneyness, d1.underlying, d1.underlyingprice) 
                    = (d2.asofdate, d2.contract, d2.strike, d2.expiry, d2.type, d2.last, d2.bid, d2.ask, d2.volume, d2.iv, d2.moneyness, d2.underlying, d2.underlyingprice)
              )
```

This will keep the rows with the smallest value in `id`. If you want to keep those with the highest `id` use `where d1.id < d2.id`.

Comment: Thanks, EXISTS is definitely faster!!