# UPDATE table in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following [my quest for db clean-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561687/postgresql-query-seems-to-be-running-on-infinite-loop), I am running into a new issue. For certain asofdate value (here '2020-08-04') I have two records on the same contract. This is how it currently looks:

```
asofdate        contract                id   
"2020-08-04"    "AAPL200807C00180000"   7632063
"2020-08-04"    "AAPL200807C00180000"   7740504
```

There are some other columns but I feel there are not important. My goal is to update the table (public."OptionsData") so that for every contract-duplicate for asofdate = '2020-08-04', the smaller id is unchanged while the record with the larger id has its asofdate updated to '2020-08-05'

Hence from my previous table, the updated version would be

```
asofdate        contract                id   
"2020-08-04"    "AAPL200807C00180000"   7632063
"2020-08-05"    "AAPL200807C00180000"   7740504
```

I tried the following (adapted) code from a previous answer:

```
UPDATE public."OptionsData" d1
SET d1.asofdate = '2020-08-05'
WHERE d1.asofdate = '2020-08-04'
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM public."OptionsData" d2
              WHERE d1.id > d2.id
              AND (d1.asofdate, d1.contract) 
                = (d2.asofdate, d2.contract)
           )
```

I also tried AS d1 in the first line, but same issue:

```
ERROR:  column "d1" of relation "OptionsData" does not exist
```

Shall I use only the d2 alias and remove the reference to d1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is *almost* correct. Postgres does not allow table aliases (`d1`) on the left side of the `SET field = some_expressiion` line:

---

```
UPDATE public."OptionsData" d1
SET asofdate = '2020-08-05' -- <<-- Here
WHERE d1.asofdate = '2020-08-04'
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM public."OptionsData" d2
              WHERE d1.id > d2.id
              AND (d1.asofdate, d1.contract) 
                = (d2.asofdate, d2.contract)
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ids are unique, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows on each day.  Then just increment the date when the `row_number()` is greater than 1:

```
update OptionsData od
    set asofdate = od.asofdate + (seqnum - 1) * interval '1 day'
    from (select od2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by asofdate, contract order by id) as seqnum
          from OptionsData od2
         ) od2
    where od2.id = od.id and od2.seqnum > 1;
```

If you want to limit this to a particular date, then use a `where` clause:

```
update OptionsData od
    set asofdate = od.asofdate + (seqnum - 1) * interval '1 day'
    from (select od2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by asofdate, contract order by id) as seqnum
          from OptionsData od2
          where asofdate = '2020-08-04'
         ) od2
    where od2.id = od.id and od2.seqnum > 1;
```